# Error del sistema &H80004005 (-2147467259) CRViewer 8.5 Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vba, crystal-reports

Estoy intentando agregar a mi proyecto de vb6.0 el componente para visualizar los reportes de Crystal Report en la versión 8.5

Después de agregar este intento guardar el proyecto, pero me da el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo las librerías y controles necesarias agregadas al proyecto para que este funcioné.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he intentado solucionar de varias formas pero no he podido, alguien que me pueda colaborar con esto.

Muchas gracias!!

---

Pude solucionar el error, pero ahora tengo otro problema. Cuando voy a abrir el visor desde cualquier opción imprimir del programa, me sale el error: Server has not yet been opened

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de este me sale el error: Causa posible: Error de Automatización y se sale por completo del programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que utilizo para abrir el reporte:

```
     If Dir(App.Path & "\repContabilidad\" & NomRPT) <> "" Then
        Dim Cra As CRAXDRT.Application
        Dim reporte As CRAXDRT.Report
        Dim nuevoVisor As New VisorCrystal
        
        Set Cra = New CRAXDRT.Application
        Set reporte = Cra.OpenReport(App.Path & "\repContabilidad\" & NomRPT)

        nuevoVisor.Show
        nuevoVisor.CRVISOR.ReportSource = reporte
        nuevoVisor.CRVISOR.ViewReport
        nuevoVisor.Caption = "Informe de Comprobante"
        nuevoVisor.CRVISOR.Refresh
    Else
        MsgBox "Archivo no encontrado : " & NomRPT, vbInformation
    End If
```

Comment: Ese error -21blablabla es un system.exit(1) sin más. El otro, H800blabla, suele estar asociado a addins no encontrados. Si vas a esa ventana y le das examinar, encuentras el dll correspondiente en la ruta que dice estar?

Comment: Hola..
Gracias por la ayuda, pude solucionar el error, pero ahora tengo otro problema.

Cuando voy a abrir el visor desde cualquier opción imprimir del programa, me sale el error:
**Server has not yet been opened** 

Después de este me sale el error:

**Causa posible: Error de Automatización** y se sale por completo del programa

Comment: Este es el código que utilizo para abrir el reporte:

 Dim Cra As CRAXDRT.Application
 Dim reporte As CRAXDRT.Report
 Dim nuevoVisor As New VisorCrystal
            
 Set Cra = New CRAXDRT.Application
 Set reporte = Cra.OpenReport(App.Path & "\repContabilidad\" & NomRPT)
    
 nuevoVisor.Show
 nuevoVisor.CRVISOR.ReportSource = reporte
 nuevoVisor.CRVISOR.ViewReport
 nuevoVisor.Caption = "Informe de Comprobante"
 nuevoVisor.CRVISOR.Refresh

Comment: Nonono. Como puedes ver, revisar código en un comentario es imposible. O respondes ESTA pregunta con tu solución y abres una nueva, o la editas si la solución era trivial y pones el problema que intentas resolver ahora. El enlace [Editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/431902/edit) está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas.

Comment: Hola, que pena.

Ya edite la pregunta al final esta el caso que me esta pasando ahora.

Gracias!!

Comment: Puede estar relacionado con el error anterior. ¿Cómo resolviste el error anterior?